# Expand Table Row to show content within table Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I came across this plugin a while back and never bookmarked it. I was hoping someone might know the name of it or link me up.

The plugin is for a table and it allows you expand on each row within the table. So if you click the "View" button within a table row then the table would open up on that row and there would be some sort of content shown below the row you clicked. The key is that it is all kept within the table and the content section below the table row does not have all of the columns of the table.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a plugin (I guess).

Basically you can reach such functionality with very simple code. For example:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>
          Somecontent
          <div class="hidden-content" style="display:none">Some hidden content</div>
       </td>
       <td>
         <a href="#" class="display-hidden">view</div>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Then the expanding script will be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.display-hidden').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().prev().find('div.hidden-content').slideToggle('fast');
  })
</script>
```

No need of plugins at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to [jExpand](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/20/Expand-table-rows-with-jQuery-jExpand-plugin.aspx).